# Can't build objective-c project when including Foundation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, osx-snow-leopard

Sorry in advance if this has been answered, I've searched repeatedly here and the in the apple docs, but haven't found out what is causing this problem. I have a iOS app that is driven by a 'layout' file that contains references to the content. I wanted to create a command line tool to optimize the content and modify the layout file if need. For example, by tiling an image and replacing it in the layout by the tiles.

I thought to create my first ever OSX tool and used the newest Xcode to create a CoreFoundation project, which gives me a main.c like this:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CFShow(CFSTR("Hello, World!\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

which builds fine. I thought to use some of the NS* classes to start working with the command line args, but as soon as I included the Foundation framework and added this line:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

I started to get tons of build errors. I think I'm missing something basic, here, but I can't see it! Did I choose the wrong template? Is there a better one? Or, what's the problem with using Foundation here?

Comment: Could it be that it is still compiled as straight C? Would it magically compile as Objective-C if you the file extension to .m?

Comment: Either that or a compiler flag. /cc @Monolo

Comment: Yup - but while I admit that I am too lazy to actually check Xcode out for this, I'd guess changing the file name is simpler, and at least easier to find in the UI...

Comment: After getting the answer I set the type in the Utility Pane and it compiled right away. The lesson for me is that a CoreFoundation project is a C project. I guess that writing iOS only has conditioned me to thinking that Xcode is all objective-c. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the file language to Objective C for it to compile. Either that or rename main.c in main.m

Comment: Duh! I feel especially stupid looking at the file for so long and ignoring the extension! That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Usually the most straightforward solutions are the ones we fail to check first :)